# Comparing NSArray values

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

So i have 2 arrays, one i have from my local sqlite db and the other i pull down from a server.

When i try to use isEqualToArray: i'll get a NO even though they are similar. This NSHipster article http://nshipster.com/equality/ told me that it's because they compare identity in the memory..? So i'll need some way of only comparing the values?

All help will be appreciated, i've been staring myself blind on this one for quite some time.

So i have 2 arrays:

```
 NSArray *arr1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"Hello",@"member",@"Janus", nil];
 NSArray *arr2 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"Hello",@"member",@"Janus", nil];
```

When i print them they look exactly the same, when i run NSSet on them like Pablo A suggest i don't get a match and either when i run `isEqualToArray` on the arrays directly. They are in order and they are always the same number, they are identically but the code won't recognize it.

Comment: Without getting into coding, think about how you want to define "equal".  Are they equal if they contain equal objects?  Does order matter? Depending on the kind of objects, you may have the same decision to make about object equality.

Comment: Two arrays are equal only if they contain equal objects in the same order. Is this true in your case? What kind of objects are in the arrays?

Comment: Yeah, sorry i didn't get into more details. 
I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I edit my answer as I realised it may fail. Here you have a better solution:

```
NSSet *set1 = [NSSet setWithArray:arr1];
NSSet *set2 = [NSSet setWithArray:arr2];

if ([set1 isEqualToSet:set2]) {
    // equal
    NSLog(@"They contain same objects");

    if(arr1.count == arr2.count) {
        NSLog(@"They are exactly the same (not checking order)");
    }
}
```

Edited according to comments.

Comment: That makes these equal:     `NSArray *arr1 = @[@"A", @"B", @"A"];` and `NSArray *arr2 = @[@"A", @"B", @"A", @"B"];`.  Maybe or maybe not...depends on what the problem needs.

Comment: I think you need `arr1.count == arr2.count` rather than checking set sizes.

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: Using my example data, both sets have a count of 2, while the arrays are 3 and 4. ( `isEqualToSet` docs actually say that it already checks the number of members.)

Comment: Actually my first solution was alredy fine, as NSSet uses unique values, so all duplicates will be removed and it will just compare unique values. But, actually, the question doesn't specify if he wants to check both arrays contain same values either using duplicates or not.

Comment: Hey guys, sorry for the sloppy question! I've updated it with some more info! Thank you for your time.

Comment: @4FunAndProfit check my solution, it should work for your example

Comment: I've tried the set and i never get true, i know the arrays will always be the same length, but this [set1 isEqualToSet:set2] is never returning true for me, even though its exactly the same when i print them to the terminal?

Comment: Exactly, it's really weird, one of the arrays is pulled from a local db? The other is from a webserver? I don't know if this is of any matter, but the program won't recognize them as equal..

Comment: Can you print both arrays?

Comment: yes i can and they look *exactly* the same when i do it

Comment: I mean if you can copy it here

Comment: aaarh, the one from the localdb is a integer and the other is saved as a NSNumber, which it apperently won't compare... Error 40 all the way..

Comment: Actually you can't store an integer in an NSArray